# Angular Material DatePicker invisible

Tags: html, angular, datepicker, angular-material

I´m trying to use the angular material datepicker in my project. The datepicker itself is invisible, but if i click in its location or where the calendar icon is, it does work. For clarity, i added a button next to the datepicker. What causes the datepicker to behave like this?

[Screenshot of invisible datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp5Vu.png)

[Screenshot of datepicker after clicking the invisible calendar icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLBi2.png)

For clarity, i have added a button next to the datepicker which does show.

My HTML file:

```html
<div>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Hello</button>

</div>
```

My imports:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CoreModule} from './core/core.module';
import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: works for me when Icopy paste you're code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwt4ds-tkruqu?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html)

Comment: Hi @jack, this is working fine, please make sure your app is setup correctly. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I discovered that 2 of the pre-built themes are considered 'Light' (deeppurple-amber.css & indigo-pink.css) and 2 are considered 'Dark' (pink-bluegrey.css & purple-green.css).

They all work is just that the light ones are visible with white or color background but not black and the dark ones are visible with black or color background but not white.

You can easily try just changing the background color of the body element.

Resources (both from the Angular Docs):

- [Theming your Angular Material app](https://v6.material.angular.io/guide/theming)
- [Theming Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the datepicker component and just use the calendar to select a date when the user clicks anywhere you want.

the turbogui-angular open source library encapsulates the mat-calendar component in a super easy to use way. First install it on your project:

```
npm install turbogui-angular
```

Then import the dialogService where you need it and call addDateSelectionDialog:

```
import { DialogService } from 'turbogui-angular';

// Inject the required dialog service into your angular component
constructor(public dialogService: DialogService) {

}

// Call for the calendar date picker
this.dialogService.addDateSelectionDialog({
        width: '500px',
        title: "some title for the calendar dialog"
    }, (selectedDate) => {

    if(selectedDate !== null){

        console.log(selectedDate);
    }
});
```

The mat-calendar component will appear and let the user pick a date.

More info here:

https://turboframework.org/en/blog/2024-02-19/easily-show-material-calendar-with-angular-to-pick-date